# Want to have checkbox already checked when data is loaded

Tags: php, json, bootstrap-table

I am using bootstrap-table (https://bootstrap-table.com/) and loading data via json.  All data is currently loading correctly - an id field, checkbox field, and name. I load the data into an array, then into the table. However, I want certain records to have the checkbox already selected, depending on certain things.  How do I pass this via the array below?

The scenario below does not work.

Here is how I am preparing my array in php:

```
$user_accounts[] = array(
  'id' => $i,
  'selected' => 'true',          -- this is the checkbox
  'name' => $name
);
```

My table is set up with these columns:

```
{ field: 'id', colspan: 1 },
{ field: 'bs-checkbox' },
{ field: 'name', align: center }
```

I get my data from an ajax call:

```
$.ajax
.....
success:  function(data);
var opts = $.parseJSON(data);
$('.userTable').bootstrapTable(load,opts);
```

I thought sending 'true' to the checkbox would cause the checkbox to be checked, but that does not seem to be the case.

My HTML is set up as follows:

```
<th data-field="id"></th>
<th data-field="state" data-checkbox=true"></th>
<th data-field="cn">Name</th>
<th data-field="selected">Selected</th>
```

Comment: can you show how you load data?

Comment: edited my information above

Comment: `checked` is the boolean attribute of an input type checkbox to indicate it is selected. Suggested reading [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/checkbox#checked).

Comment: I'm using the plugin bootstrap-table, so these docs do not apply.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in `bootstrap-table` `check` method as:

```
$('.userTable').bootstrapTable('check', 1);
```

Where 1 is the row index that of the row that you want to be checked.

In your case you should place this code after table has loaded.

Comment: That makes sense, except I am comparing 2 arrays in PHP.  Any matches in one of the fields and I want to "check" the box when loading.  When I do the comparing in PHP and then send json data back (via ajax), all the checkboxes are checked (despite the JSON data showing otherwise) - state is "true" for only 2 items, yet all the checkboxes are checked.  If I change the data after PHP, the checkboxes are correct.  I'd like to do this via PHP, because I need to check later to see if a checkbox has been unchecked.